# How to check out a JHipster project in multiple development environments

Tags: jhipster

I'm evaluating JHipster; it looks great for rapid development!

Maybe a novice question: I see that the generated `.gitignore` ignores certain things, e.g.

```
/node/**
/node_modules/**
```

So, if I check in the generated project to a repository, and then some other developer in my team checks it out in his environment, the project would not work in his environment. Would it?

Was curious to know how to handle this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your git repo won't track node packages, others using your git repo will need install node.js, then run npm install to download all the node packages. 
It's similar to them having to have java and maven installed on their environment.

Update: A developer will run 'git clone '. The source (not including node or bower) will be on their workstation. Once they've installed node.js, they'll run 'npm install' and the node directories will be created automatically for your project by downloading them from the Internet. That way you don't need to keep all your node libraries in your own git repository ...just their package name and version in the package.json file (similar to maven dependencies in pom.xml).

Comment: I see, thanks. But then, how exactly will a new developer clone the existing project? Won't clone need an empty directory?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if you have any other questions

Answer (score 0):

No one should commit the node_modules or bower_components to git, what you would do is share the project like you share the maven projects.

Write in the read me what needs to be done to get them ready, for example the installation of yo, bower, grunt or gulp and generator-jhipster.

What is very nice about liquibase, each developer can have his own version of the database, and every commit has its own database version.

What we our team does, if a developer adds something to node js package.json then we mention it in the comment: npm install needed and the same applies for bower.

That way you keep all your environments clean, and if you would like to install continuous integration like "Jenkins or Teamcity" then you make sure Jenkins is building rebuilding the whole project.

Comment: I see, thanks. But then, how exactly will a new developer clone the existing project? Won't clone need an empty directory?